# make "plugins" with C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am developing a key value database.
https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4

In order to be as fast as possible I heavily use C++ templates and most of the types not really known until compile time.

I want to add plugins / modules there - in separate shared libraries (file.so) .

In order to do that, I will need to have C-style struct with some function pointers. However, once again I do not know my "real" types.

Shall I use function(s) with `void *` or there are some pattern that helps for this?

This is what I am thinking about, but seems very complicated and I do not particularly like it.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A{
    int process(int i) const{
        return i * 2;
    }
};

struct B{
    int process(int i) const{
        return i * 4;
    }

};

// existing template function
template<class T>
void useT(T const &t, int i){
    printf("%d\n", t.process(i));
}

template<class T>
void useVT(const void *v, int i){
    const T *t = reinterpret_cast<const T *>(v);

    useT(*t, i);
}

extern "C"{
    void useA(const void *v, int i){
        return useVT<A>(v, i);
    }

    void useB(const void *v, int i){
        return useVT<B>(v, i);
    }
}

int main(){
    B b;

    useB(&b, 5);
}
```

Comment: "most of the types not really known until compile time." can you clarify? Is this a typo? Usually it doesn't really matter whether a type is known before you compile your code....

Comment: type is known, but because is template, the template does not know the type.

Comment: "the template does not know the type" ?!? Yes it does. The type is `T`. In your code you instantitate it for `T == B`

Comment: are you asking how to generate / avoid the functions `useA` and `useB` ? because there could be also a `struct C {};` and then you need `useC` ?

Comment: If you need a real plugin you need dynamic polymorphism of any form. So use virtual methods or pointers  (exposing some methods from dynamic library) to functions or `std::function`. Templates are giving extra performance by statically binding functions and this is in opposition to plugins concept.

Comment: @idclev463035818 this is the idea, must be like that because of the shared library.

Comment: @MarekR thanks. Any easy pattern for this, or my code is relatively fine?

Comment: Factory pattern is a standard in case of plugins.